# Bootloop and inaccessible recovery mode. Fastboot stops when connected to PC

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, fastboot, boot-loop

I have ASUS Zenfone Max Pro M2. I installed Pixel Experience and recently tried to update it, but it stuck in a boot loop.
My bootloader is unlocked and the device is not rooted.
Also, the Recovery mode is not accessible.
Fastboot mode is accessible but when connected to and PC, a black screen is visible with a message "press any key to power off".

If there is any way that can reset the device and install any ROM (root or without root).
Please share it.

Opened Fastboot:
[image: Opened Fastboot]

After Connecting to PC:
[image: After Connecting to PC]

Entering `fastboot devices` on PC:
[image: Entering fastboot devices on PC]

Comment: hi @alecxs I've added screenshots of what happening after i connect it with the PC.

Comment: just after I connect to PC, `Fastboot Devices` screen disappeared

Comment: I've already tried different OS, USB, and PCs but the same thing is happening. Even if somehow a system recognized Fastboot device, the second command does not work and last screen appears on phone that says "press any key to shutdown"

Comment: https://youtu.be/-NLJG9CL-uU

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-fix-press-any-key-to-shutdown-when-unlock-bootloader-or-run-fastboot-cmd.4180389

Comment: thanks @alecxs, gonna try it out.